# Express after registering .html - includes no longer work

Tags: express, pug

I have a mix of jade and plain vanilla html files.

I have registered the html file extension like so :

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.register('.html',require('jade'));
```

However, I can not include the html template from within a jade one.

I have tried the following within the jade template
content.jade

```
include ../page_content/user/index
//and
include ../page_content/user/index.html
```

now nothing renders.

Anyone had any joy with this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't do that. Jade cannot render plain vanilla html files.

But [EJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs) can, so instead do this:

```
app.register('.html', require('ejs'));
```

Let .jade files be compiled by jade and html files by ejs.